# What does using array index like this [0,1,2] means?

Tags: arrays, c

How can an array have an index like [0,1,2]?
And why is [0,1,2]=[2] 
Code:

```
int main(){
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    a[0,1,2]=10;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
1 2 10 4 5

Comment: If you enabled compiler warnings, you would notice that `0,1,2` is an expression where 0 and 1 are ignored. So frankly it's doing `a[2]=10;` thus setting the value at index `2` to value `10`. And since in C array indexes start at `0`, that is setting the 3rd item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma operator (`,`) evaluates both expressions and returns the second one (see, e.g., [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558/2422776)). I.e., `0,1,2` will evaluate to `2`, so `a[0,1,2]=10` will result in `a[2]=10`, which explains the output you get.

Comment: I wonder what's the purpose for this behavior of evaluating commas.

Comment: @MarkoBorković As far too often, probably avoiding to break old source. In this case, really stone-age old code.

Answer (score 0):

1. `a[0,1,2]` will be treated as `a[2]` aka the other indices are ignored.
   To test this try: `printf("%d ",a[0,1,2]);` you will see it prints the
   value in index 2 only.
2. To change the values of multiple indices then you either do it
   manually or iterate over them. For example,

`a[0] = 10;`

`a[1] = 10;`

`a[2]=10;`

OR

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    a[i]=10;
```